# Adding a user to sudo group vs creating a sudoers file

Tags: sudo

What is the practical difference between:

- adding a user to `sudo` (Debian) or `wheel` (RHEL) group

  ```
  sudo usermod -aG sudo/wheel <username>
  ```

vs

- creating a file named `username` with the following contents in `/etc/sudoers.d/`

  ```
  username ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL
  ```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Effective difference?  Not much.  Biggest I can think of is that by adding the user to the `sudoers` group (or whatever group is needed) the user needs to log out/in or use  `newgrp` to really become a member of that group and be able to `sudo`, whereas a file under `/etc/sudoers.d/` wouldn't require that extra step.

Long term maintenance, etc. with more than just one user involved... the group membership may be "better" - it really comes down to work flow, etc. at that point and it rapidly moves this question even further into that grey murky area known as "opinion based answers". Obviously there may be some technical reasons behind choosing one over the other (ie, for the `www-user` to `sudo` and you don't want to or can't start/stop the webserver) but "which is better" is almost always opinion and situation based.

Comment: Please be aware that `newgrp` changes that user's **primary** group, which [logging out and logging back in again does not do](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76889494/3499840).

Answer (score 4):

The only practical difference that I can see is in the situation where the `sudoers` file is a standard that is shared (deployed) amongst different machines. (And the user/group database is for some reason not shared. An unlikely situation, IMO.)

In this instance the user added to the `sudo`/`wheel` group will be able to execute any command as any user only on that machine, whereas the the user with an explicit entry in the `sudoers` file will be able to execute any command as any user on every machine.

Comment: we could combine our answers into a SuperAnswer!  if you want ot copy/paste mine into yours as an edit, i'll cheerfully delete mine.

Comment: @ivanivan thank you. I think it's useful to keep both answers, if only to shows that there is not really much difference but that we've addressed the issue from different directions.